# What is your favorite whiteboard interview problem?

Tags: interview, algorithms

Just as the title says, what is your favorite whiteboard interview problem, and why has it proven effective for you?

Junior, senior, Java, C, Javascript, PHP, SQL, pseudo-code, etc.

Comment: A problem I hated was an Einstein's Puzzle. http://www.stanford.edu/~laurik/fsmbook/examples/Einstein'sPuzzle.html I could not do it in 30 minutes. But then I got pissed off, and found this: http://games.flowix.com/en/index.html So I trained to do a harder 6 x 6 x 6 problem on average in 20 minutes. I think I can handle 5 x 5 x 5 in 30 minutes now. Whatever stupid puzzles the employer will throw at me - I will remember them and will ace them next time. There are so many good puzzles.

Comment: @Job: None of which will tell you anything about how an employee will perform on the job.  Unless, of course, you spend all of your work time solving these kinds of puzzles instead of getting actual work done.

Comment: @Robert Harvey you mean you are in a business that makes money some other way than solving puzzles? I had no idea... ;)  That puzzle is fun though.  As a side note, a company I used to work for used *actual* IQ tests as the first step in their screening.  I'd like to find some good whiteboard questions to separate the best candidates, not to simply screen them.

Comment: @Renesis: As a developer, I can see how solving a puzzle identifies problem solving and analysis skills, but developers also must know how to translate that solution into code.  Solving a puzzle only shows half of that execution.  It's the difference between solving a Rubix cube and writing an algorithm to solve a Rubix cube.

Comment: @Robert Harvey I agree, I am specifically looking for coding problems, not just thinking problems.

Comment: The bounty will go to the answer that I like the most, that also has a reasonable amount of up-votes (no answers qualify yet).

Comment: After reading this, I had to write a FizzBuzz program just to see how fast I could do it.  Do they have to get it right in one shot, or are you watching the thought process? ... Now that I've done it once, I wonder if it's suspicious if I knock it out in one try with no hesitation...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I ask the candidate to **design a solution to a problem I actually encountered** in my day to day work. Doing so, I try to create a dialog between me and the candidate. I try to discuss about the design he is building as if I had never thought about the problem before.

What I try to evaluate is whether we are able to understand each other, and whether we can talk about a technical problem without confusion.

#### Concrete example

(For a java desktop developper)

Design an API to handle the **navigation history of a web browser** (previous page, next page, list the 10 previous pages), and that can be reusable in many parts of the application (here I give concrete examples in our app). Then, sketch up an implementation.

I like this one, because it's simple enough, it's easy to illustrate, it can be solved step by step (add additional behaviors without breaking everything), it allows to talk about edge cases and error handling, and it also allows to talk about data structures.

Answer (score 40):

I've found this one extremely illuminating when interviewing candidates and filtering out those with no business being there. It is similar in complexity to Fizz Buzz, but focuses on database skills.

```
Assuming the following basic  table structure
Documents (DocID, DocDate)
Keywords (KeyWordID, KeyWord)
DocumentKeywords (DocID,KeywordID)

Write a query to return the following:
Part 1: Documents with a DocDate after 4/1/1995  
Part 2: Documents that contain the keyword "Blue"  
Part 3: Documents that contain the either the keyword "Blue" or "Yellow"
Part 4: Documents that contain the both the keywords "Blue" and "Yellow"
```

I let them write it in any SQL variant they want, and am not too picky on minor syntax problems. I mainly want to know that they understand basic relational DB concepts.

Most candidates can get through part 3 with no issues at all. You'd be amazed how many think that the answer to part 4 is just to change the operator from OR to AND in the where clause.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue w/#4. Your documents only have one keyword per row, so you can't have a cell equal both "Blue" and "Yellow" *taps knows knowingly*

Comment: Yep. Honestly, I'd give people partial credit if they just realized that much. Many of them would argue vehemently that just saying Where Keyword="Blue" and Keyword="Yellow" would solve the problem.

Comment: What do you do when they fail part 4?

Comment: Ooops! I can see myself falling for (4) in an interview. @Job: As *interviewer*, I'd ask the candidate to explain the query, hoping that he stumbles over his problem to see how he deals with that. (that usually tells you more than a candidate acing your questions on first try.)

Comment: @job - First I drop hints like "Are you SURE." If they stick to their answer, I tell them it is wrong and give them a chance to correct it, if they can.

Comment: How about converting them to linq questions instead of SQL? Then, how do we represent these document and keyword classes?

Comment: This is a clever question, but I haven't been a part of any interviews where I've felt I needed or wanted to dig this deep into SQL skill.

Comment: I like that its quite easy to use on a whiteboard since it's short and the syntax required is quite simple.

Comment: @Renesis, I'm not so sure this is really digging deep.  This seems pretty good for finding out if someone has basic SQL query skills.  I'm actually shocked at how few developers have these basic skills these days.

Comment: @Mark & Renesis it's going to depend on your business domain, plenty of coders never have to interact with a DB at all, but if you do then I can see the value

Comment: @jk01, maybe I have an old school attitude about this, but IMO a well-rounded developer should have some DB knowledge, if not to access via code, but to at least understand the domain by experimenting with queries. Without this, a developer has a pretty significant blind spot. It's also EXTREMELY useful for system support and troubleshooting. Abstraction is fine to help simplify development and increase productivity, but I've seen way too many assumptions made because this is so often abstracted away. I could go on, but this could be a whole other debate I'm sure is taking place elsewhere ;)

Comment: Can I write it in LINQ? SQL is so last year!

Comment: @Cameron - Umm. No. The point isn't whether you understand the SQL language. It is whether you understand database concepts. If you can write LINQ and not SQL, that would also be a problem.

Comment: So someone can't understand databases without SQL?

Comment: I'd argue that you can't really even understand LINQ if you don't know what's happening under the covers.

Comment: @JohnFx LINQ isn't written for databases, so you can understand it without understanding a DB.

Comment: @David - Which underscores my point anyway. With my series of questions I'm looking for understanding of relational databases.

Comment: Have you considered, that in many document-based storages this is absolutely straight forward and that relational databases may not always be the best solution? You could just as well expect everybody to know enough xpath to extract this data from an XML. Unless you're hiring a DBA, this should be actually hidden in the database abstraction layer.

Comment: @back2dos - Look, don't get offended just because you can't answer it. There may be a lot of other technologies that make this simpler, but we use a lot of SQL databases and I recruit people that know how to use the technologies we use, not make excuses for why they shouldn't have to answer my interview questions.

Comment: I am not offended. I just think the interview question is fit for a specific field only, which is not even "databases" as you say, but really SQL. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Frankly,  I don't even hold them to writing perfectly valid SQL. As long as they can write pseudo-sql that demonstrates they understand the underlying concepts I give them some credit. I'm not looking to see if they know the SQL language, I am looking to see if they understand the database concepts.

Comment: just for those wondering, i gonna post one possiblee solution: SELECT * FROM Documents JOIN DocumentKeywords USING ( DocID )  JOIN Keywords USING ( KeyWordID ) WHERE KeyWord IN ('Blue','Yellow') GROUP BY DocID HAVING COUNT(DocID) > 1

Comment: Gosh, what a great question for candidates who claim strong SQL skills! There are so many ways to do it: join against documentKeywords twice, use subselects, use intersect, but all solutions require some SQL ability beyond simple inner joins. @Joe's group by answer is also a reasonable approach, but fails if there are duplicate rows in documentKeywords.

Comment: @Joe I suggest instead 
"HAVING max(KeyWord = 'Yellow') = 1 AND max(KeyWord = 'Blue') = 1" I wrote up a bunch of possible solutions here
http://nohat.net/sql-interview-question

Comment: Thanks again for this awesome interview question. I have now used it in four different interviews and my coworkers are using it now too.

Comment: @nohat - I'm curious. How often are you finding that it is screening out candidates that were claiming strong SQL skills, and how often do you lose them at each step? My biggest surprise when I started using it was how many didn't know how to construct a join without a GUI query builder.

Comment: @JohnFx of the 4 candidates who I have used with so far, all claimed strong SQL skills—some of them were even interviewing for an ETL position. Two got it right and were otherwise very strong candidates, and so I gave them “hire” recommendations. The others got up to step 3 without much trouble but either couldn't solve part 4 or thought the solution was just to change the OR to an AND and refused to believe me when I told them otherwise.

Comment: @nohat - That coincides pretty much with my experience. After so many protests on #4 I wound up building the sample DB and having it ready for them to actually try the query when they insist the OR/AND switch would work and end the argument.

Comment: @JohnFx as one more follow up I have discovered that candidates who use "implicit join" (SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3 WHERE ...) rather than explicit joins (SELECT * FROM table 1 JOIN table 2 ON ...) for parts 2 & 3 are pretty much guaranteed to not be able to handle part 4. Only those who know and use "real" JOIN syntax "get it".

Comment: http://pastie.org/1608675  (Can I have a job?...)

Comment: @syrion: why not use `joins` for Q3 and Q4.

Comment: @Kishor: I would, now.

Comment: I had something like nr. #4 in my DB exam in college. The teacher warned us about that issue multiple times during classes. So what did he do ? He failed everyone who got it wrong at the exam. Needless to say I was among the 20 % who passed... Though I think he was a little unfair with the others...

Answer (score 20):

"Draw for me on the whiteboard the design of the last project you worked on, without revealing me any sensitive detail."

Comment: How would you define the design?  Are you looking for a class diagram?  Another UML diagram?  A basic sketch of the tiers?

Comment: I call them baloongrams. ;) Just draw cicles, put names and connect them with named arrows. 
I don't care about his application but about the fact he understood it.

Comment: +1. For people, who had a job previously, this is definitely one of the best things you can do. If they can explain how the project was structured, its already worth a lot. If they have an idea as to why it was structured in that particular way, or how some things could be done better, than this is really a huge plus.

Comment: @justkt: The importance is, that the interviewee gets the information accross. It matters little how. I have met people, who really know UML, who can't explain a thing with it, and people, who can explain complex systems with a few squiggly lines.

Comment: This is a really nice way to see if the applicant understood the project and can communicate what he/she knows.

Comment: +1 for naming something I'd never thought of but now plan on using in future interviews

Comment: How on Earth is anybody supposed to draw the design of a project without revealing any sensitive detail?

Comment: usually sensitive details are about data, not project design. I don't want to know XYZ inc. patented solutions or how they store data of the clients, just the overall design of his project. He could change all the names if he really understood his code.

Comment: +1 I don't think you could survive at my company without being able to do this well.  When colleagues have questions we do this all the time.

Answer (score 14):

My favorite which encompasses a few disciplines is to count the number of nodes in a binary tree given the interface (in C#):

```
public interface IBinaryTree<T>
{
    IBinaryTree<T> Left
    {
        get;
    }

    IBinaryTree<T> Right
    {
        get;
    }

    T Data
    {
        get;
    }

    // Other properties and methods not germane to this problem.
}
```

and just for fun, here's the implementation, though the interviewee need not see this.

```
public sealed class BinaryTree<T> : IBinaryTree<T>
{
    private readonly IBinaryTree<T> left;

    private readonly IBinaryTree<T> right;

    private readonly T data;

    public BinaryTree(
        IBinaryTree<T> left,
        IBinaryTree<T> right,
        T data)
    {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public IBinaryTree<T> Left
    {
        get
        {
            return this.left;
        }
    }

    public IBinaryTree<T> Right
    {
        get
        {
            return this.right;
        }
    }

    public T Data
    {
        get
        {
            return this.data;
        }
    }

    // Other properties and methods not germane to this problem.
}
```

and the assistant class:

```
public static class BinaryTreeNodeCounter
{
    public static int CountNodes<T>(this IBinaryTree<T> tree)
    {
        // TODO: What goes here?
    }
}
```

The solution I like to see is this:

```
public static class BinaryTreeNodeCounter
{
    public static int CountNodes<T>(this IBinaryTree<T> tree)
    {
        return tree == null
            ? 0
            : 1 + tree.Left.CountNodes() + tree.Right.CountNodes();
    }
}
```

As it demonstrates knowledge of:

- how a tree (binary tree in particular) works
- the recursive definition of a binary tree
- recursive methods and how base cases stop recursion
- what counting a single node means
- interfaces as a contract
- (less important) knowledge of C# syntax:

  - generics
  - extension methods
  - ternary operator

Comment: Could it be an extension method?

Comment: In this day and age, yes.  We were coding in VS 2005 at the time, hence the sparse syntax.

Comment: Why use an extension method when you've got the source code for the original class? That's not what extension methods are for.

Comment: 'spose I could have gone a level deeper and show the candidate an interface that this class implements.  The gist is that the original class should not need to be modified - some entry-level developers would love to add stuff to the class to make the request "easier".

Comment: holy crap that looks a lot like java!

Comment: I like that question. You should also ask them to implement it without recursion (running in a limited memory environment use an explicit stack). Also ask if they could find a way to speed up the process (optionally hinting them toward multi-threading).

Answer (score 13):

Implement `strcpy`, `strcmp` and friends.

Comment: I ask candidates to implement `atoi()`.

Comment: You would be amazed at how many people can't implement `strdup()`.

Comment: That's only fair if the job opening is for a C programmer.

Comment: In the interview for my current job, interviewer asked me to implement `strrev()` or string reversing function. My white-board solution impressed them and I am doing job now.

Comment: @crisaycock atoi() is easy. itoa() is devious

Comment: I'd ask them to implement fopen.

Answer (score 12):

Two questions that have elicited interesting whiteboard discussions for me are

1. "Please can you explain in as much detail as you like how a web browser gets a generated page"
2. "Please explain how Java Hibernate works"

They start off simple and then get progressivly more complex.

Comment: ehi, I'm not even qualified to judge the answers... I think that for the second one you need 12 black candles and a goat...

Comment: The second is easy, your OS saves the processor cache and stack and the contents of your RAM to the hard drive, and then restores it when the computer is turned back on.

Comment: However, the first question could take days to explain.

Comment: @Malfist I meant the Java Hibernate persistence framework.

Comment: I think Malfist was joking!

Comment: @Paul Stephenson Yeah, but just to be sure...

Answer (score 8):

I don't like to use a puzzle or a design question as a whiteboard question. I prefer straightforward, simple, questions, that test the candidate's ability to write some code. My favourites are:

1) Write a function to reverse a singly linked list.
(It takes a while before they realise they need 3 pointers.)

2) Given a binary tree, find the depth of the binary tree.
(This question tests their ability to write recursive code. Lets me check if they have their base case intact.)

3) Write a procedure for binary searching an array of integers.
(Like Jon Bentley says (in Programming Pearls), many people tend to make mistakes writing binary search. One can then follow up with finding bugs, writing test cases, running through the code, etc..)

Comment: +1, I like your approach doesn't make any sense to ask someone Dynamic programmins or such concepts when they are hardly used in business programming + Emphasis should be on code quality as well and not on the solution alone.

Comment: I don't mind design questions, but I once interviewed with a guy whose hobby was doing puzzles, and he had some horrid questions. It was like me asking somebody martial arts questions.

Comment: Probably should make sure people know you mean "sorted array" in (3) right?

Answer (score 7):

We used this at one company I worked for.

We handed the candidate a piece of paper used for tracking time.  It was a real timesheet  used by one or our divisions.  We asked the candidate to walk us through the design process for creating a better time tracking tool.  No boundaries, didn't say what language etc., just want to see how good the candidate was at "full lifecycle".  It gave us a real insight into how they gathered requirements.  How they structured database tables, what kind of UI they might do.  Communication skills were obviously needed for this task.  It was usually done in a room with several large white boards and lasted as long as 2 hours.

We hired several people using this process and if they did really well on the task they did really well for us.  If they were marginal and we decided to hire them anyway (separate topic) they were marginal programmers.

Answer (score 6):

I use a problem that is relevant to my programming domain.

If I develop web applications, I want to see how they might draw up a web form that deletes records, and what approach they might take to removing the record from the database, for example.  This tells me if they know basic database principles, how they interact with the user to verify deletion, and if they know what a soft delete is.

I don't have a favorite.  The problem I choose will vary greatly depending on the job.

I don't care whether they can solve the problem completely or not in an interview, what technologies and languages they use, or how crappy their code looks on a whiteboard.  I am looking for a thought pattern; I want to see if they know how to think through and solve problems.

Comment: +1 For the last paragraph, which is all important.  Usually it is not the answer that matters in such things, but the path taken to get there.  As all my maths teachers ever said *"show your working!"*

Answer (score 4):

My favourite was one a friend of mine used.

> Write me a function to generate/print/store the first "n" prime numbers and then explain how it works and how efficient it is.

It works well because:

1. It's an algorithmic question so it requires the interviewee to be able to think and then explain their thinking - so you can see how their brain works.
2. It's language independent.
3. Hardly anyone gets it completely right (there's usual an edge case they miss (1 or 2 normally), or they don't handle negative numbers, so you get to see how they handle bugs and being told that they're wrong.
4. Most do it as a simple but very slow sieve (e.g. 80% of people will check of n is a prime by dividing n by all integers less than n), which gives you lots of scope for conversations about how they could improve the algorithm based on space/time trade offs e.g. "why are you dividing a number by 4 if you already know it's not divisible by 2?" or "You've worked out that you only need to divide by all prime numbers less than sqrt(n), but that requires you to store those numbers somewhere, so what are the implications of that?")

There's no need for them to get the answer right. If someone can think and explain their thinking then they're a long way down the road for being a good candidate.

Comment: I once got an interview question, where I was given a very obfuscated block of C code, and asked to find out what it did.  In a very round about way it printed every other prime number out.  300 people applied and they offered me the job as apparently I was the only candidate that told them what the purpose of it was, as opposed to getting the values out.  So yes, +1, primes are a good check.  Particularly if they come up with a sieve, though that trades off computational complexity for space complexity.

Comment: 1 isn't prime..

Comment: @Thorbjørn - well obviously, but a good percentage of the routines I've seen written to solve this problem have told me that it is

Comment: then they have a bug :)

Answer (score 3):

Something called aff_z, which was part of my engineering school's C examinations and was used as a "dummy" test to have students fail when coming back from holidays (our marking system implied that failing a test stopped the marking, so failing that dummy test would invalidate your whole test. Forces you to pay attention to moronic details). I did reuse it once or twice during interviews.

Anyways... I forgotten the exact formulation but it was something like this...

```
Write a function taking a single char parameter named c and returning nothing (void).
You function must satisfy the following requirements:

 - if c is bigger or equal to 0, then print 'z' to standard output
 - if c is stricly smaller than 0 , then print 'z' to standard output
 - in any other case, print the letter 'z' to standard output
```

The sad thing is that not only some students would come up with extremely convoluted solutions when the answer is fairly obvious, but that some would even manage to fail.

And believe it or not, it did happen during interviews as well.

Running it in interviews was fairly fun, as some applicants would start writing the possible branches and then realize what is wrong (obviously, if you only ask them orally, that is quite understandable that they do so as you speak... but if you give it in writing, I find it puzzling...)

It's dumb, but I guess it's a minimalistic screening (similarly, when hiring JS programmers, I always ask how to declare a variable, and then depending on their answer whether or not using var makes any difference at all. Quite often a sad moment, honestly.)

Comment: Did you ever have candidates in interviews feel insulted by this? Or think you were simply having fun at their expense instead of conducting a serious interview?

Comment: @Renesis: I had a few looking at me with a smirk first. Some of which failed the test. In general the good candidates laugh if off. For the JS programmers for instance, I had quite a lot of candidates who failed the interview answer with a "duh, `variablename = variablevalue;`" whereas the good ones would just laugh on the phone or in person and directly tell me what the different would be with or witout `var`).

Comment: @Renesis: Plus, I couldn't really care less if some get offended . It's not discriminative in any way. If they get offended, then I'll assume they're the kind of person who don't like to be put to the test or questioned. I never really had applicants feeling I had fun at their expense though. I usually even apologize **before** asking very simple questions as it might feel like a waste of time for the good ones. But the thing is, it's not a waste of time for me. Not asking them would ne, on the longer run.

Comment: @Renesis: And more often that not, what I got after the smirk/laugh/offended look was an ashamed expression and an apology from the one who failed it or started writing the branching for the whole test when they realized it was useless. Yes, I do have some fun giving this test, but I wouldn't give it if it wasn't for a good reason.

Comment: Personally, I would have a mental facepalm when reading that and would wonder if someone else wrote the question for the interviewer to make fun of him.

Comment: @user9094: Well, I was honestly a bit shocked the first time I saw it too. But it does help to spot the ones who cannot do anything, and the ones who don't focus. Like I said, I wouldn't care if they feel offended. If it's so easy, then they can do it. It's just sad that so many fail it. And it is sad that we have to put good programmers through it, I'll give you that.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends what you are looking for, as an organisation that does a lot of dynamic web work involving images, I tend to like to ask a geometry question pertinent to the job.  In any case, I tend to ask a geometry question, as I find it a good maths test that is nice and visual and can show a candidates ability to visually present their working and methodically work through a problem.

For advanced candidates, I occasionally give the following question:

> This image shows a crescent moon.  The width of the crescent from B to D
>   is 9cm and between E and F, 5cm. C is
>   the centre of the larger circle.
>
> a) Please calculate the area of the crescent.
>   [image: Crescent Moon Maths Question]
>
> b) Describe the calculations necessary to resize an image to fit in to the inner circle from any given size, and position it within the circle if the centre point is known.

For an easier question I usually give the same sort of question, but use the "square within a circle within a square" example.  Though this is very easy, so I would expect perfect algebra on it.

[image: Square inside a circle inside a square]

Over and above that, I tend to ask them to knock up an algorithm for generating all combinations of a variable length data set.

Comment: The answer for a) is 128.75? (don't know if I made any mistake). I like it, but it's more about geometry though.

Comment: @Hoàng Long: I made it 643.24cm^2, though the numerical answer is unimportant, the method is where the marks are.  Computing contains a great deal of geometry, particularly on the web or in anything with graphics.  I think this sort of puzzle tests the essence of programming well, problem solving, plus gives their mathematical skills a work out.

Comment: I see someone downvoted this without explanation, very pathetic.

Comment: Not pathetic, just not enough time, but now that I'm through my commute, here we go: -1 for not being programming related. I, personally, have never been in a technical interview, but I would question the relevance of the problem. I do graphics for a living building dynamic layouts through scripting and automation, and this problem has zero relevance with the problems I am faced with daily. Even with the complicated layouts that I do, the math is really more "checkbook math" with rectangles than anything.

Comment: @Philip Regan: Thank you for making your point.  Layouts within web do tend to be entirely rectangular in nature, though image generation within those rectangles is not necessarily, circles and all manner of shapes come up.  Never had to embed one image within an irregular frame?  Done any 3D work?  The above problem I have actually used, generating surface area for best cost/fit algorithms in the print industry.

Comment: @Philip Regan: There is no need for a question to be directly within the job description in any case.  The purpose of the question is to identify the right underlying mentality and capabilities.  When I went for my interviews for university, many years ago, for Computing, none of the top institutions asked me a single question on computing - all maths, science or engineering questions, as is appropriate.

Comment: @Orbital: My processes place irregularly shaped art all the time (I'm in college textbook publishing, so I get everything from photos to anatomical illustrations), but I let the layout applications do the math for me. Certainly, that's not web work specifically, but more of my work creates web products and I still have yet to come across anything more than what I have so far. [...]

Comment: [...]  I still think the question should be more relevant to programming if only because "thinking to code" (my term for lack of a better one) is a different context than solving a geometry problem To be perfectly honest, I wouldn't be able to that problem but I still do layouts that pass strict technical and editorial review. It just seems an unfair question in its current form for its intended purpose.

Comment: Also, sorry for the delay in commenting. I don't like to downvote as a rule and doubly so without commenting as to why. My downvote isn't about the question itself, it certainly has purpose for you, I just don't think it has a proper context in a programming interview.

Comment: -1 because geometry is a good candidate for Just In Time Learning, and does not reflect on my ability to create quality software.

Comment: @Malfist: When I hire, I train - I do not expert operatives to come to the table with full knowledge of the languages in play, because that can change.  A weaker mind can be strong with practice in a particular area, but that may lack transferability.  A strong mind is a better asset for a company.  [Not implying you have a weak mind at all, just stating why I think it is valid.] Also, with such questions I would allow them to look up formulas online if they wanted - it is the ability not memory that is tested.

Comment: @Philip Regan: I downvote myself where necessary, I have no qualms about that if people have a point to make, regardless of whether or not I disagree with them, each to their own.  Just think downvoting requires a comment, and you commented, so great.  When I posted my rebuke, I was unaware of the delay you encountered.  So sorry if you took any offence from my comment, it would only have applied to a non-comment and in any case was a tad harsh.

Comment: @Philip Regan: You say you let the layout applications do the math for you.  Well, in the case I mentioned, it is the layout applications that are being written, LOL.  So it does come in to the equation at some point.  The "intended purpose" can be many things in programming, my "intended purpose" is usually to find someone very good at solving complex analytical/mathematical problems, as I find most programming boils down to that.

Comment: @Philip Regan: Incidentally, you say you would not be able to achieve the problem, which was very respectable for you to say.  You seem smart, the sort of work you do involves similar skills, I imagine you would get a lot further with it than you think.  It scares all candidates I have ever shown it to, if not initially then once started.

Comment: @Orbling, but all that is testing is if they've memorized the proper formulas, not their ability to solve complex analytical/mathematical problems.

Comment: @Malfist: Copied from my answer directly to you: *"Also, with such questions I would allow them to look up formulas online if they wanted - it is the ability not memory that is tested."*  No memory involved, just approaching a problem and solving it.

Comment: @Philip, I would consider analyzing a geometrical problem to figure out a formula to give the right answer, to be _extremely_ programming related.

Comment: @Malfist, I don't think that the formula for the area of a crescent moon is commonly memorized.  The 5 cm distance is non-trivial to use properly in the problem.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: As stated, I let them look stuff up - it's a test of capability, not memory.  I strongly believe that the approach within an interview should not use a false reality where memory and luck play an important role, the job is not like that.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: With regard to the formula for the moon, I would be looking for candidates to use basic algebra and geometric properties to find the solution, rather than a specific knowledge of crescents.  It should be easy enough for anyone with A-Level standard maths, which is a minimum requirement to code effectively.  At least people should be able to head in the right direction.  The only wrong answer is "I can't do it".

Comment: @Thorbjørn: Right. I read the question very literally, however, and @Orbling didn't ask for a formula or function, @Orbling asked "solve for *x*" which is an entirely different context.

Comment: @Orbling: Since it would be an open-book question, I would definitely take a crack at it (and maybe I'll tackle it later this weekend). That seems a fair way to handle the situation as well. I've found the only closed-book tests I have ever taken were in school; As "they" say: life is just an open-book test.

Comment: @Philip Regan: Aye, good proverb.  True too, still seems very difficult considering!  I think someone hid a lot of the books. ;-) Merry Christmas.

Comment: I enjoyed this problem. I hope you don't mind me sharing my solution to part (a).  The diameters differ by 9cm, so if the inner circle has radius r, the outer circle has radius r + 4.5.  The area of the crescent is the difference in the areas of the circles: pi(r + 4.5)^2 - pi * r^2.  All that's left is finding r.  Define C as the point (0,0), then point E is at (0, r - 0.5) (because CE is 5cm less than the larger radius).  The inner circle is shifted right 4.5cm, so its equation is (x - 4.5)^2 + y^2 = r^2.  Plug in (x,y) = (0, r - 0.5) and solve for r.

Comment: This gives r = 20.5cm, meaning the area of the crescent is 643.24cm^2 (or 6*10^2 cm^2 if we care about significant figures).

Comment: +1 because I think it's a good question for a job that requires geometry. There's plenty of reasoning involved, not just plugging into a formula.  That said, I know some good programmers who'd be tripped up just because they haven't so much as had to think about circles in 10 years -- but the question doesn't ask for a suitable question for *any* developer interview.  The currently top-voted SQL question (which I also like) is at least as job-specific.

Comment: @Tim Goodman: Well done, good reasoning. I agree with your point on relevance to the job.  I think it is particularly useful for checking jobs that involve geometry, which is remarkably high if you have to work with any graphics or user interfaces.  I think it is of more general use to determine a) how good a candidate's maths skill is, even if their geometry is weak, it needs some algebra, which programmers all need. b) whether they panic with a hard question or go and find out how to do it.  I don't want to hear "I can't do that".

Answer (score 3):

The best **FizzBuzz** answers I've seen are:

**SQL Server 2008**

```
;WITH mil AS (
 SELECT TOP 100 ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.column_id ) [n]
 FROM master.sys.all_columns as c
 CROSS JOIN master.sys.all_columns as c2
)                
 SELECT CASE WHEN n  % 3 = 0 THEN
             CASE WHEN n  % 5 = 0 THEN 'FizzBuzz' ELSE 'Fizz' END
        WHEN n % 5 = 0 THEN 'Buzz'
        ELSE CAST(n AS char(6))
     END + CHAR(13)
 FROM mil
```

**C# (simple)**

```
foreach (int number in Enumerable.Range(1, 100))
{
    bool isDivisibleBy3 = (number % 3) == 0;
    bool isDivisibleBy5 = (number % 5) == 0;

    if (isDivisibleBy3)
         Console.Write("Fizz");

    if (isDivisibleBy5)
         Console.Write("Buzz");

    if (!isDivisibleBy3 && !isDivisibleBy5)
         Console.Write(number);

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**C# (clever)**

```
 Enumerable
  .Range(1, 100)
  .Select(i =>
    i % 15 == 0 ? "FizzBuzz" :
    i % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz" :
    i % 3 == 0 ? "Fizz" :
    i.ToString())
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

Comment: You may want to add which particular SQL dialect this is written in.

Comment: Looks nice with the functional style.

Answer (score 2):

For databases I go with:

```
Table: Things

ID       Name
1        Bodkin Van Horn
2        Hoos-Foos
3        Hoos-Foos
4        Hot-Shot
5        Marvin O'Gravel Balloon Face
6        Snimm
7        Marvin O'Gravel Balloon Face
8        Marvin O'Gravel Balloon Face
9        Dave
```

Write me some SQL that will de-duplicate a table like this based on the name (and I don't care which ID I get back but whichever one is returned must be valid for that name).  So the table once the correct SQL has been applied to it will present something like:

```
Table: Things

ID       Name
1        Bodkin Van Horn
2        Hoos-Foos
4        Hot-Shot
5        Marvin O'Gravel Balloon Face
6        Snimm
9        Dave
```

I like it because:

- De-duplication is a real world problem
- There are a bunch of ways to do it
- I think that pretty much all of those ways need you to either understand (slightly) more complex SQL (essentially GROUP BY and HAVING) or the ability to reason through chaining multiple simpler statements.
- Because of this last bit even if they're struggling with syntax or whatever, you can ask them what they're thinking and talk through it that way.
- It references Dr. Seuss

(This is where I find that there is some entirely trivial way of doing this and I've been over complicating it all these years).

Comment: I guess I don't know what counts as "entirely trivial"... Something like `SELECT min(ID), Name FROM Things GROUP BY Name` would work, right?

Comment: @Tim - That gives you the count for everything.  I only want those with duplicates.  Manually edited the results doesn't count, assume it's scaling to millions of rows.  It is an easy problem but in my experience 80% of people claiming to know SQL can't get even as far as your first stab.

Comment: @Jon: Not sure what you mean by "That gives the count for everything".  From your example solution, it looks like what you want is one row for each distinct name.  From your comments it seems like maybe you mean something like `HAVING count(Name) > 1`, but then I guess your sample answer should omit Bodkin Van Horn, Hot Shot, Snimm, and Dave.

Comment: @Tim - You're right, it's really unclear.  I'll edit when I get a few minutes.

Comment: @Jon Hopkins: OK, I get what you're doing now.  You want to find all of the rows with duplicates so you can kill all but one of each, leaving only the de-duped rows.  I was initially thinking that you just wanted a query that returns the rows while omitting duplicates, which is why it seemed really simple.

Comment: I guess I would do this: `DELETE FROM Things WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM Things GROUP BY Name)`.  Do you have a preferred solution?

Comment: @Tim - That would work.  No preference - one of the things I like about it is that there's no one right answer and there are different options.

Answer (score 2):

I look for a couple of things in candidates that I have interviewed. For reason I can't describe online, we get pretty poor candidates, and I've come to expect it, so I'm pretty easy on them. Even still, I look for:

- Awareness of design.

  "Show me the table structure for an address book program that has Contacts with first and last names that can have multiple Phone Numbers with a description of the number (cell/home/work/etc.)"

  I'm not looking for a UML 2.0 spec diagram here, a simple bubble diagram here is fine. As long as it's reasonable.
- Knowledge of working with a database (ie. SQL)

  1. Write a query to get all of the phone numbers for people with the last name "smith"
  2. Write a query to get all of the customers in the database, and the phone numbers for the ones with the last name "smith"
- Knowledge of testing

  Assume a method with the signature `public IEnumerable<PhoneNumber> GetPhoneNumbers(string lastName)` exists that returns the results of your query from earlier. Assume that if you pass a null into the method, it throws a NullReferenceException. Write a test to demonstrate this functionality.

  Write a test that demonstrates that GetPhoneNumbers will return a home phone number of (123)456-7890 for someone with the last name "smith".
- Knowledge of how to write some code

  Implement a method that will fulfill the requirements of the tests you wrote.

---

Considering the number and quality of the applicants we've gotten, I've interviewed everyone who's ever seriously applied. I've hired no-one.

Comment: In SQL #2, are you talking about doing this all in one query? Is the purpose just to gauge understanding of left/right or inner joins?

Comment: @Renesis: Yes it is.

Answer (score 2):

I usually let them sketch a block diagram of the last system they've worked on, asking about the relations between the blocks and than let them elaborate on the block they were working/in charge on. You can learn many from this exercise, like how one looks beyond his small domain, how much is it important to him to know 'where' he is acting, also you can learn about the role he was playing, was it a key or side role.

Answer (score 2):

If I were to interview a software developer, I'd ask him to design a software and describe hardware requirements to remove duplicate entries from an arbitrarily large file containing a full name on each line. I leave some parts of the problem description ambigous purposefully. Then I challenge him to see if he understands analysing and clarifying requirements, different trade-offs, data structures and algorithms, I/O (secondary storage), software and hardware technologies, scalability, etc.

I think it is a small yet challenging problem, revealing applicant's knowledge and abilities in many computing areas.

Answer (score 2):

`Implement function/method(on c/c++/c# whatever), which calculates n-th item of Fibonacci sequence`

Many guys could stuck on this. 
If some solution is given - usually it uses recursion. 
After that:

`Implement the same via 'for'-loop`

Can't tell you, how many fellows fail to complete both tasks - 50% of candidates.
That's why I like it :)

Comment: What if the first implementation is done via a for loop?

Comment: Recursive version is proposed to implement. Usually after for-loop guys successfully implement recursive version.

Comment: Or you could implement this as a single statement:  `fib(n)=round(power(PHI,n)/SQRT5)`.  PHI and SQRT5 are constants representing the golden ratio (1.618...) and the square root of 5, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

My favourite C++ whiteboard problem is to have the candidate implement

```
Vector3 a(1, 0, 0), b(0, 1, 0); // Mathematical 3D vectors
double c = 7.0;
double d = a * c;
Vector3 e = a * b;
```

From this I can learn

- if the candidate recognises that you can't overload on return type (indication of juniour-level C++)
- if the candidate knows how to return a temporary and implement casting operators (indication of intermediate-level C++)
- if the candidate can do basic vector math (important for our application domain)

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is to start with asking the prototype of printf. Then given a low level API printc(char c), which will print one character, implement printf. Gives all sorts of interesting responses like the stack is part of the CPU. As you might have guessed I am from a C and embedded background.

Comment: I don't get the "stack is part of the CPU" thing.

Comment: Anyone who knows anything about computer architecture would know that. To me it's completely unrelated, so the guy is demonstrating his ignorance.

Comment: @aufather: If I remember correctly, you have to call `varargs()` or some function like that. Am I correct? I've only done it once to say I did it a while ago.

Comment: @barjak - Once you start implementing printf, you will need to access your stack, and I have got responses that stack is in the CPU.

Comment: @Michael - In the embedded world, you need to know your platform architecture really well. So this question quickly weeds out the ignorant pretty early on.

Comment: @Michael - Even I am not very sure about the exact syntax of the macros used. But if you have a sound understanding of a computers architecture, you should be able to figure it out. Again if the candidate comes up with a macro definition which cannot be implemented, I proceed to ask him how to implement that macro.

Answer (score 1):

Write an algorithm for the following problem: **Given a number *n*, output the total number of (unique) binary trees that have *n* nodes.**

Thus, for *n*=0 and *n*=1, the answer is 1. For *n*=2, you have 2: the root node, and then the second node either to the left or the right.

You can gain insight into design techniques and to see if they think of recursion or memoization or the dynamic programming solution.

[See also this StackOverflow [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352776/the-possible-number-of-binary-search-trees-that-can-be-created-with-n-keys-is-giv) for the related, but different, case of binary-search trees.]

Comment: So a UI Programmer who doesn't know dynamic programming is a bad programmer ? For the heck of it any business programmer who can't recollect dynamic programming is bad ? A lot of teens at topcoder will walk through a dynamic programming problem but please have a look at the code they write.

Comment: @Geek: Remember that "whiteboard" problems are a way to see someone's thought process. Dynamic programming problems should belong in this discussion, as they are very popular with Google, among others.

Comment: I don't disagree but I have two questions. 1. Solving the unknown ? DP problems become a walk in the park if you have solved some problems in the recent past or you still remember the concept out of college. Someone who has forgotten it will definetely not do well on the white board. 2. If someone is struggling to solve a problem there is no way you can quantify his code quality. What about giving a problem on something like a LinkList or Strings or Arrays such that the person can solve the problem and write code.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily expect an interviewee to get it right, either, however some companies will.

Comment: @Geek: “a … programmer who doesn’t know dynamic programming is a bad programmer?” – **yes**. That said, I agree that thinking in dynamic programming isn’t trivial when you’re not used to it. But *knowing* it is an absolute must.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bowl with 200 fish in it. Of these fish 99% are not guppies. How many fish should you remove so that 2% of what remains are guppies. Show your work.

This is about confusing requirements. It is said this way to change perspectives multiple times during the same question. It is meant to see if they can figure out what is really going on.

You would be surprised how many people get it wrong.

Comment: Add two 12 Inch Oscars in the bowl they will remove 98% of the guppies very soon.

Comment: What happens if you remove a guppy?

Comment: 1% guppies, = 200 x 1% = 2 (200-2 = 198 other fish), where 2 = 2%, remaining fish = 98% = 98 (1:1). 98 = 198 - 100 => `answer = 100`. [Assuming you can selectively pick the other fish. If removing guppies, there are other answers.]  Good question, you would be surprised how few people handle that well, though it should be child's play for a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few favourites, but here are a couple that nearly always come up. Most of the time I'm doing final round technical (C++) interviews so favour longer and more open questions which lead to new areas of interest. There's no 'right' answer, just an opening to other conversation.

1) Implementing a basic shared pointer, explanations of where there's deficiencies compared to tr1 or boost's shared pointers in their implementation, how it should be used etc.

2) A code review. For experienced hires we expect them to be able to confidently review some provided code for design problems, errors, coding horrors and potential maintainability problems. Also, of course, how they'd fix it; and sometimes how they'd give that message to the junior developer they're shooting down.

Answer (score 1):

One question that I've been using ever since it was used on me is the following:

> Write a function to print all numbers
>   between 1 and 100.

A large part of the reason that I've been using it is due to the fact that you can then take there solution and move in various directions:

> How would you modify the function to
>   print all numbers between 1 and 1000,
>   10000, or *n* ?

Their answers to these questions could give you insight as to how they respond to changing requirements as well as if they can recognize performance considerations. A strong candidate might respond with a question in regards to what the function is needed for an how often it would be called.

Moving in a different direction:

> How would you change things if you
>   knew this function is going to be
>   called several times a minute and
>   performance is a concern?

I use this as a way of checking their lateral thinking. Since calculating prime numbers can be slow as the max value gets larger it sometimes makes more sense to just use some sort of calculated or pre-calculated look-up table that is adjusted on the basis of the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one to provoke some thought--It's straightforward, involves a bit of math, and checks the candidate's knowledge of basic computer design (overflow, numeric representation, etc):

Write a program (or procedure) that takes a pair of integers X, Y as input and determines whether X*Y is evenly divisible by 10. IMPORTANT NOTE: X and Y may be large enough that X*Y overflows the largest integer type available on your machine.

---

Sample solution:

```
T_BOOL MultipleOfTen(int x, int y)
{
    return((x%2==0 || y%2==0) && (x%5==0 || y%5==0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How would you represent a standard 52 card deck?  Any programming language is fine.  How would you shuffle the cards?

Comment: vector<Card> with C++' shuffle function :)

Answer (score 0):

Fill in the following method: *PS* A mode of a number is the number (in the list) which has the most occurrences.

```
public int getMode(List<Integer> numberList) {


}
```

This is to see of effecient is your code.

Answer (score -2):

How would you represent a spare matrix that's relatively large... say 1000x1000 but has at most 100 non-zero entries?